# Taking screenshot of GRUB without VM

Tags: grub2, screenshot

Is there any way that I can take screenshot of my GRUB menu without loading my operating system in a virtual machine? 
Or if I want to take a screenshot of my GRUB menu using a VM, do I have to install a fresh copy of the OS to that VM?

Answer (score 3):

You can't take a screenshot on a physical machine during the boot process. You may do it in a VM of course.

Comment: But do I have to install another OS in that VM?

Comment: You need an Ubuntu iso image for that. What virtualization software do you want to use?